# Compiling v4l2loopback on raspberry pi seems to work, but kernel module won't load

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian, v4l2loopback

After following the steps in order to compile v4l2loopback as shown here:  https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/pivariety/how-to-access-and-program-the-pivariety-camera-using-command-line-python-opencv-and-gstreamer/#22-create-a-virtual-video-node-access-by-python

I end up with a module that is on the right lib/modules/version, but I can't load it.

```
[13952.844293] v4l2loopback: disagrees about version of symbol cpu_hwcap_keys
[13952.844320] v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol cpu_hwcap_keys (err -22)
[13952.844401] v4l2loopback: disagrees about version of symbol device_create_file
[13952.844410] v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol device_create_file (err -22)
[13952.844431] v4l2loopback: disagrees about version of symbol _dev_err
[13952.844440] v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol _dev_err (err -22)
[13952.844771] v4l2loopback: disagrees about version of symbol device_remove_file
[13952.844781] v4l2loopback: Unknown symbol device_remove_file (err -22)
```

Comment: Are you sure you compiled this module using the kernel headers matching your running kernel with the same configuration options? Alternatively why don't you just install `v4l2loopback-dkms`? It should handle everything.

Comment: APT brings the same headers as the running kernels, so that part is fine. About using v4l2loopback-dkms I was under the impression that it needed to be compiled with support for this camera specifically. I'm just following the instructions from their website.